# Lottery question-probability of pairing Mega numbers on two different tickets

Tags: probability

Sorry to burden you with ASLQ (another stupid lottery question), but y'all are better at probability calcs than I.

Last Tuesday I bought $10$ Mega Millions throws in $2$ tickets of $5$ each.  The first ticket had the following Mega numbers (the sixth number that is a must-match for jackpot winners--the range of possibilities is $1$ through $25$):

$A-10   B-22    C-03    D-15    E-25$

The second ticket purchased $5$ minutes later at another store had the following Mega numbers:

$A-10   B-24    C-22    D-03    E-25$

As you can see with the second ticket I drew four pairs to the first ticket and among the $10$ picks had only $6$ unique Mega numbers.  This feels decidedly non-random.

? Is this correct:  The probability of one match in the second ticket is $\frac{5}{25}$. The second match is $\frac{4}{24}$ and so on, yielding $\frac{1}{2}, 530$ as the probability of drawing four pairs in two tickets.

Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

Since you are picking 5 mega numbers at random and each pick is independent, the probability follows the binomial distribution.  Using the probability formula for the binomial, we get:

$$P(4matches) = \binom {5}{4}\Big(\frac {1}{25}\Big)^{4} \Big(\frac {24}{25}\Big)^{5-4} = \frac{24}{1953125} = 0.000012288$$

Which is a very small probability!  You are very lucky to get 4 matches.

To explain the formula a little:

There are $\binom {5}{4} = 5$ ways to choose 4 out of the 5 mega numbers to be matches.
Each match has a probability of $\frac{1}{25}$ and we have 4 of them, so we just multiply them because of independence, hence the raising to the 4th power.  Lastly, we have the probability of *not* matching the remaining 5-4 = 1 mega number, and that has a probability of $\frac{24}{25}$, which is multiplied at the end, again by independence.

Comment: Rabid, thanks for your answer.  I thought it was a "lucky" draw. in fact the odds appear to be lower than the Mega Millions posted odds for a 4+0 ticket, which is 1/38,792.  That is worth $500 in the game...After you posted I found a formula here https://www.statisticshowto.datasciencecentral.com/probability-and-statistics/binomial-theorem/binomial-distribution-formula/  that yields ~1/2,000,000.  It muliplies 4!/5! by your result.

Comment: @user605667, you should have gotten the same answer with the formula because that is exactly what I used.  If you multiply my answer by 4!/5! = 1/5 then that yields the probability for a _particular_ combination of 4 matches, say the one where you match every mega number but the second one, i.e., MXMMM (where M = match, X = no match).